# PostgreSQL `createuser` without specifying username

Tags: postgresql, createuser

I ran:

```
$ createuser --pwprompt
```

and saw:

```
Enter password for new role:
```

I expected to be prompted for a username, so at this point I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

The `man` page synopsis says that the username is optional:

> ```
> createuser [connection-option...] [option...] [username]
> ```

The only other info given is:

> username
>
> Specifies the name of the PostgreSQL user to be created. This name must be different from all existing roles in this PostgreSQL installation.

What user is `createuser` operating on when none is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to read this part of the documentation (it took me a while too):

> `--interactive`
>
> Prompt for the user name if none is specified on the command line, and also prompt for whichever of the options `-d`/`-D`, `-r`/`-R`, `-s`/`-S` is
>   not specified on the command line. (This was the default behavior up to PostgreSQL 9.1.)

You didn't specify `--interactive`, so you are not prompted.

In consequence, PostgreSQL chooses the default user: unless `PGUSER` is set, that is your operating system user.

So, assuming that you are operating system user `postgres`, you effectively did the following:

```
createuser -U postgres postgres
```

which is of course silly and would have led to

```
createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "postgres" already exists
```

if you hadn't chickened out and interrupted execution.